# Cannot resolve getExternalStorageDirectory() / MEDIA_MOUNTED / getExternalStorageState()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Everything was working fine this morning. I've even rolled back all the code changes i've made yet the app wont build/run! It's driving me nuts. I guess it must be an application setting which has changed?

Here's one of the code snippets (although, as previously mentioned, not sure the code is important as it was working perfectly until today);

```
 public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
  String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
  if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Showing the Gradle Console helped by giving me a tiny bit more information...

```
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                                  ^
  symbol:   method getExternalStorageState()
  location: variable Environment of type String
C:\SVN\MainActivity.java:1106: error: cannot find symbol
```

Wait... Environment shouldn't be of type String. Ooops! I had declared a String with this reserved name. I changed my String variable name and everything is working again.

Strange as i'm convinced this was working earlier but I guess not...